# Spring aliasFor for Annotations with Target(PARAMETER)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am trying to use the Meta-annotation of spring using the aliasFor annotation to create a custom annotation for the springs  **RequestParam**

Simply 'extend/replace'

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface RequestParam {

   @AliasFor("name")
   String value() default "";

   ----
}
```

with my annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface QueryParam {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestParam.class, attribute = "name")
    String name() default "";

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestParam.class, attribute = "required")
    boolean required() default false;

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestParam.class, attribute = "defaultValue")
    String defaultValue() default ValueConstants.DEFAULT_NONE;

}
```

This way it throws the Exception

```
org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationConfigurationException:   @AliasFor declaration on attribute [name] in annotation [package.QueryParam] declares an alias for attribute [name] in meta-annotation [org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam] which is not meta-present.
```

Problem is that without the RequestParam annotated on the QueryParam this doesn't work. And it is not possible to put the RequestParam as it PARAMETER targeted.

```
@RequestParam <--This is not possible. 
public @interface QueryParam
```

So is there another way to achieve this  ?

Answer (score 11):

Basically what you want to achieve is not possible now, at least for the Spring v 4.3.3 There are main two problems, the first one is the fact that annotations like `@RequestParam` are declared with `@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)` which make it impossible to be used as part of meta annotations. Furthermore, Spring MVC looks up annotations on method parameters using `org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getParameterAnnotations()` which does not support meta-annotations or composed annotations. But if you really need some customizations there you can use `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` instead of meta annotations.

So you code will look something like

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface QueryParam {

   String name() default "";

   boolean required() default false;

   String defaultValue() default ValueConstants.DEFAULT_NONE;

}
```

Then using the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` add the custom logic which you need.

```
public class QueryParamResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

   public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
       return parameter.getParameterAnnotation(QueryParam.class) != null;
   }

   public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
       QueryParam attr = parameter.getParameterAnnotation(QueryParam.class);
       // here you can use any logic which you need
       return webRequest.getParameter(attr.value());
   }
}
```

Then we need to register our `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
      argumentResolvers.add(new QueryParamResolver());
    }
}
```

And last lets use our custom annotation

```
 @GetMapping("/test")
 public String test(@QueryParam("foo") String foo){
      // something here 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and I entered the wrong package for GetAmpping. I must import «import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping»  .