# Unable to create meta-annotation for @RequestBody in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I want to create a meta-annotation, called `@QueryRequest`, for Spring's `@RequestBody` like shown in below.

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RequestBody
public @interface QueryRequest {
}
```

However, it throws a compilation error called,
`java: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration`

When I searched in the internet, it tells me to verify the correct `@Target` type. Anyway, as you can already see my `@Target` and `@Retention` values, they are as same as what Spring's `@RequestBody` is, but still above error is thrown.

I have successfully created meta-annotations for `@Target=ElementType.METHOD` or `ElementType.TYPE` types, but I could not make work above annotation.

Anybody know what is actually wrong with above meta-annotation?

Comment: I am guessing it is because @RequestBody can't be used on other interfaces and hence on other annotations. Not sure what is the workaround

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40861154/2148365

Comment: `@RequestBody` contains the following `@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})`, so you can use it only in a parameter. If you take a look to `@Documented` one, for example, you will see `@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)`, that is the reason why is possible to use it in `@RequestBody`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @RequestBody is annotated `@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)`you can only add this annotation on a parameter. Here you are trying to apply the annotation on an annotation. In order to achieve that `@RequestBody` should have been annotated with `@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)` or with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE)`.

For example this code will not work because you cannot annotate QueryRequest on an annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface QueryRequest {
}
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@QueryRequest
@interface NextQueryRequest
```

However this will work, because you are allowing QueryResult to be put on an annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface QueryRequest {
}
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@QueryRequest
@interface NextQueryRequest

 @Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface QueryRequest {
}
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@QueryRequest
@interface NextQueryRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel has explained why this happens with an example.

Also, anyone who is looking for **a workaround** should read this answer as @Michiel mentioned above.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40861154/2148365